# How to detect if a script in Julia got "Killed"?

Tags: bash, julia

So I'm running a Julia (v 0.6.3) script in a bash script called `./run.sh` like so:

```
./julia/bin/julia  scripts/my_script.jl
```

Now the script prematurely terminates. I'm sure of this because it doesn't finish outputting all the data it's supposed to. When I run a parsing script (written in Python) afterwards, it fails because of missing data.

I *think* that it terminates to insufficient RAM allocation (I'm running the script on a Docker container). If I bump up the allocated RAM the script works fine.

To catch this error in my Julia script I did the following:

```
try main();
catch e
    println(e)
    exit(1)
end

exit(0)
```

On top of that, I updated the bash script to check if the Julia script failed:

```
./julia/bin/julia  scripts/my_script.jl

echo "Julia script returned: $?"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Julia script failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

However, no exception is printed from the Julia script. Furthermore, the return code is `0`, so the bash bash script doesn't detect any errors either.

If I just run the the script directly from the terminal, at the very end of the output there's the word `Killed`. Immediately after I ran the command `echo $?` and I get `137`, which is definitely not a successful return status. So it seems Julia and bash both know the script is terminated, but not if I run the Julia script from within a bash script...?

Another weird thing is when I run the Julia script from the bash script, the word `Killed` doesn't appear at all!

How can I reliably detect whether a script was prematurely terminated? Is there a way to get the reason it was killed as well (e.g. not enough RAM, stack overflow, etc)?

Comment: `[ $? -ne 0 ]`: `$?` contains return code of last command. Here from `echo` and not from `julia`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then` checks if the `echo` before it successfully completed (See Cyrus's comment).

Sometimes it makes sense to put the return value in a variable:

```
./julia/bin/julia  scripts/my_script.jl
retval=$?

if [ $retval -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Julia script failed with $retval"
  exit $retval
fi
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked 100%! Although I should note that my Julia command is actually piped, so `retval=$?` wasn't enough, but `retval=${PIPESTATUS[0]}` did the trick. Either way, the `echo` command was polluting the `$?` variable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

ps: Reports a snapshot of the status of currently running processes.

```
ps -ef | grep 'julia'
```

T.

Comment: That only tells you if the process is currently running or not, but not if it finished successfully or not.